# Подключение к БД PostgreSQL с локальной и удалённой машины

Tags: linux, postgresql, permissions, psql, datagrip

Имеется БД PostgreSQL для хранения логинов к серверу CalDAV (`DAViCal`). К ней не удаётся подключиться.

```
root@server:/# systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2020-11-14 10:51:18 UTC; 19h ago
    Process: 815 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 815 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 14 10:51:18 it-server-1 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Nov 14 10:51:18 it-server-1 systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.
root@server:/# psql davical -c 'select username, password from usr;'
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

И как подключиться к БД, если пользователь есть в PostgreSQL, но его нет в Ubuntu?

pg_hba.conf (некоторые закомментированные строки удалены):

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
local   all             postgres                                peer
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
local   davical    davical_app   trust
local   davical    davical_dba   trust
host davical davical_app md5
host davical davical_dba md5
```

Логи (эти строки повторяются в логах ):

```
2020-11-14 06:10:00.685 UTC [30884] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.4 (Ubuntu 12.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2020-11-14 06:10:00.685 UTC [30884] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-11-14 06:10:00.688 UTC [30884] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-11-14 06:10:00.710 UTC [30885] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-11-14 06:09:58 UTC
2020-11-14 06:10:00.718 UTC [30884] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-11-14 06:10:15.148 UTC [35875] davical_dba@davical LOG:  provided user name (davical_dba) and authenticated user name (root) do not match
2020-11-14 06:10:15.148 UTC [35875] davical_dba@davical FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "davical_dba"
2020-11-14 06:10:15.148 UTC [35875] davical_dba@davical DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 94: "local   all             all                                     peer"
2020-11-14 06:15:57.528 UTC [30884] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2020-11-14 06:15:57.533 UTC [30884] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2020-11-14 06:15:57.544 UTC [30884] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 30891) exited with exit code 1
2020-11-14 06:15:57.544 UTC [30886] LOG:  shutting down
2020-11-14 06:15:57.568 UTC [30884] LOG:  database system is shut down
2020-11-14 06:16:29.536 UTC [700] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.4 (Ubuntu 12.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2020-11-14 06:16:29.537 UTC [700] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-11-14 06:16:29.540 UTC [700] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-11-14 06:16:29.651 UTC [715] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-11-14 06:15:57 UTC
2020-11-14 06:16:29.674 UTC [700] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-11-14 06:38:26.928 UTC [700] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2020-11-14 06:38:26.942 UTC [700] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2020-11-14 06:38:26.951 UTC [700] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 721) exited with exit code 1
2020-11-14 06:38:26.952 UTC [716] LOG:  shutting down
2020-11-14 06:38:26.978 UTC [700] LOG:  database system is shut down
2020-11-14 06:38:55.269 UTC [760] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.4 (Ubuntu 12.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2020-11-14 06:38:55.271 UTC [760] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-11-14 06:38:55.274 UTC [760] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-11-14 06:38:55.400 UTC [785] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-11-14 06:38:26 UTC
2020-11-14 06:38:55.448 UTC [760] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-11-14 07:01:10.417 UTC [1680] root@davical FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
2020-11-14 07:01:46.528 UTC [1693] root@root FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
2020-11-14 09:43:14.691 UTC [5722] client@davical FATAL:  role "client" does not exist
2020-11-14 09:56:17.018 UTC [760] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2020-11-14 09:56:17.023 UTC [760] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2020-11-14 09:56:17.032 UTC [760] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 792) exited with exit code 1
2020-11-14 09:56:17.033 UTC [787] LOG:  shutting down
2020-11-14 09:56:17.062 UTC [760] LOG:  database system is shut down
2020-11-14 09:56:41.379 UTC [681] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.4 (Ubuntu 12.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2020-11-14 09:56:41.380 UTC [681] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-11-14 09:56:41.383 UTC [681] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-11-14 09:56:41.421 UTC [681] LOG:  end-of-line before authentication method
2020-11-14 09:56:41.421 UTC [681] CONTEXT:  line 4 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf"
2020-11-14 09:56:41.421 UTC [681] LOG:  end-of-line before authentication method
2020-11-14 09:56:41.421 UTC [681] CONTEXT:  line 5 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf"
2020-11-14 09:56:41.421 UTC [681] FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
2020-11-14 09:56:41.423 UTC [681] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
2020-11-14 10:51:15.644 UTC [766] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.4 (Ubuntu 12.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2020-11-14 10:51:15.645 UTC [766] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2020-11-14 10:51:15.645 UTC [766] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2020-11-14 10:51:15.649 UTC [766] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-11-14 10:51:15.708 UTC [766] LOG:  end-of-line before authentication method
2020-11-14 10:51:15.708 UTC [766] CONTEXT:  line 6 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf"
2020-11-14 10:51:15.708 UTC [766] LOG:  end-of-line before authentication method
2020-11-14 10:51:15.708 UTC [766] CONTEXT:  line 7 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf"
2020-11-14 10:51:15.708 UTC [766] FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
2020-11-14 10:51:15.710 UTC [766] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

Comment: Может, psql -U...?

Answer (score 4):

> Process: 815 ExecStart=/bin/true

Начать, пожалуй, стоит с того, что вы смотрите решительно не тот сервис. `/bin/true` однозначно не похоже на что-либо, делающее какую-то полезную работу.

Судя по `starting PostgreSQL 12.4 (Ubuntu 12.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)` - могу угадать что вам нужен `systemctl status postgresql@12-main`

Ну а дальше вопрос уходит полностью в сторону и заключается в двух вещах:

### База у вас просто не запущена

Прежде чем подключаться к базе, её, конечно, надо запустить. Вы определённо изменили `pg_hba.conf`, но внесли некорректные с точки зрения базы настройки. О чём база и ругается в свой лог: `end-of-line before authentication method`, а ошибки чтения файла конфигурации расцениваем фатальными. Потому общий вердикт `could not load pg_hba.conf` и база отказывается стартовать пока не будут исправлены настройки.

### Ваши изменения pg_hba некорректны

Вы добавили записи вида

```
host davical davical_app md5
```

Тогда как записи host требуют [соответствующий формат](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

```
TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
```

`ADDRESS` (как для `TYPE` `local`) подключений не может быть пропущен. Более того, при указании IP адреса это должен быть строго `CIDR` формат с указанием маски сети. Указать просто `192.168.1.2` будет так же неверно, должно быть `192.168.1.2/32` для указания правила для одного хоста.

### Порядок правил pg_hba имеет решающее значение

Как видно по логу, изначально вы получали FATAL'ы при подключении к базе. И вот почему:

Когда вы подключаетесь через `unixsock` - это тип подключения `local`. PostgreSQL просматривает правила по порядку и находит

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

База и пользователь указаны `all` - значит применяем этот тип аутентификации. Всё дальнейшие правила значения не имеют, они проверяться никогда не будут. Даже если там указано `trust`.

Аналогично записи но уже для tcp/ip подклююючений:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
host davical davical_app какой-то-CIDR md5
host davical davical_dba какой-то-CIDR md5
```

Последние две не имеют решительно никакого смысла, т.к. из-за расположенного выше более широкого правила они никогда проверяться не будут. (`0.0.0.0/0` - это любой IP)

Если локальным пользователям желательно ходить по паролям, то резонно заменить `local all all peer` правило на два:

```
local all             postgres                                peer
local all             all                                     md5
```

Тогда, в соответствии с порядком проверок, для административного пользователя `postgres` будет выполняться проверка `peer`, а для всех остальных - по паролю.

---

Никогда не используйте `trust`, а открывать базу на весь мир `0.0.0.0/0` - это всё равно плохая идея даже несмотря на использование аутентификации.